# How to auto filter a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter column "I" which has the header "Stock" to show only columns with a value more than "5" in sheet name "Order in Units".

I get a debugger.

```
Sub AutoFilter_Number_Examples()
'Examples for filtering columns with NUMBERS
 
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim iCol As Long
    'Set reference to the first Table on the sheet
    Set lo = Order in Units.ListObjects(1)
  
    'Set filter field
    iCol = lo.ListColumns("Stock").Index
   
    'Clear Filters
    lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    With lo.Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:=">5"
    End With
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want ?  (Column D for example)

```
Sub AutoFilter_Number_Examples()    
    On Error Resume Next
    Columns("D:D").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    On error goto 0
    
    Columns("D:D").AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">5"
End Sub
```

I add an error handler for showallData because otherwise if data are already unfiltered it will fail.

Comment: You should add a `On Error GoTo 0` after the ShowAllData, since you don't need the error handler after

Comment: Yes, this is another way to do it @romulax14 but I think it's equivalent :)  Your welcome Jonathan ! ;) (You could make it with the macro recorder as well)

Comment: @Macronaute No it isn't, using `On Error Resume Next` tells Excel to ignore all errors below this line and just move to the next line when there is one. In your situation you don't want Excel to ignore all errors, just the one caused by the ShowAllData. So you should put `On Error GoTo 0` after the ShowAllData to tell excel to stop ignoring errors after that line. It resets the error handler. Without that, OP won't be able to debug since every error will just be ignored. An ignoring handler begins with `On Error Resume Next` and finishes with `On Error GoTo 0`, with code between.

Comment: Ok sorry @romulax14, I thought `On Error Resume Next`  was just working on the next line !